# Javascript to get the active li href name

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I need to get the href name of the active

on the tab selected on my page.
[As shown in the code below, since "href: popular" is active, I want that to be returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjzuh.png)

I want to capture this is a JS variabe using javascript. Can anyone help me with this please.

I have used the below code but no luck

```
function() {
  var element=document.querySelector('ul.uk-tab tabs > li');
  var content=element?element.textContent:undefined;
  return content;
}
```

Comment: `document.querySelector(".uk-active a").getAttribute("href")` ?

Comment: Hello! A tip to keep things usable around here: please post an actual code snippet in your SO questions, not links to pictures of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is tagged with google-tag-manager you should not write custom Javascript yourself (GTM already contains a selector engine).

Go to variables, new, select "DOM Element", switch the Selection Method dropdown to "CSS Selector", enter the selector from the comments or answers (or an "attitribute contains" selector such as li[class*="active"]>a if you are not specifically after uk-active, but all active links).

This will return the innertext property of the selected element, or, if you want an attribute value, you can enter the name of the attribute in the respective text field:

[image: GTM DOM variable settings]

Answer (score 0):

Here, in a snippet, the solution that @bertdida already suggested in the comment above:

```js
let el=document.querySelector(".uk-active a"),
    hrefrel=el.getAttribute("href"),
    hrefabs=el.href,
    text=el.textContent;

console.log(`hrefrel: ${hrefrel}\nhrefabs:  ${hrefabs}\ntext: ${text}`);
// or, combined as an object:
console.log({hrefrel,hrefabs,text})
```

```html
<section class="section tabs-container homepage main-container" data-tabs-container-tabifier data-containerid="tabgrp-collections-and-reading" data-getitemcount="2">
  <ul class="uk-tab tabs" data-tabs>
    <li role="tab" aria-expanded="false" class><a href="#firstplace">Latest</a></li>
    <li role="tab" class="uk-active" aria-expanded="true"><a href="#someplace">Popular</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

I modified the `href` of your `<a>` a little bit as otherwise the result would be pretty meaningless.

Comment: Thanks. @Eike solution makes sense as GTM is being used. However, i modified Bertida's solution to get the output i need. document.querySelector("ul.uk-tab.tabs > li.uk-active > a").outerText.